# Read CSV with OOP Python

Tags: python, csv, oop

i'm new to OOP in Python. So, I want to read CSV files using OOP.
I have a CSV file with 5 columns separated by a comma.
I want to read that CSV file, with each column stored in a table of the new dataframe.
So, suppose I have data like these:

```
1434,"2021-08-13 06:31:59",unread,082196788998,kuse.hamdy@gmail.com
1433,"2021-08-13 06:09:41",unread,081554220007,ritaambarwati1@umsida.ac.id
1432,"2021-08-13 05:35:07",unread,081911075017,rifqinaufalfayyadh@gmail.com
```

I want the OOP code to read that CSV file and store it to a new table like these:

```
id     date                 status  number        email
1434   2021-08-13 06:31:59  unread  089296788998  kuse.hamdy@gmail.com
1433   2021-08-13 06:09:41  unread  081554271927  ritati1@yahoo.com
1432   2021-08-13 05:35:07  unread  081911075017  rifqinaufalfayyadh@gmail.com
```

I tried this code:

```
import csv
class Complete_list:
    def __init__(self, row, header, list_):
        self.__dict__ = dict(zip(header, row))
        self.list_ = list_

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.list_

data = list(csv.reader(open("complete_list.csv")))

instances = [Complete_list(a, data[1], "date_{}".format(i+1)) for i, a in enumerate(data[1:])]
instances = list(instances)

for i in instances:
    j = i.list_.split(',')
    print(j)
```

Somehow, I could not access the value of each list separated by the comma and put it into a new dataframe with multiple columns. Instead, I got the result like this:

```
['date_1']
['date_2']
['date_3']
```

Comment: What do you expect ? You give the string `"date_{}".format(i+1)` to `list_` so that is normal you have only that into the result

Comment: Your class doesn't seem to have much of a point. `self.__dict__ = dict(zip(header, row))` seems very suspect

Comment: You comment my answer, but no here, what do you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest , you are better of using libraies like pandas. but this is how i would approach it.

```
class complete_list:
    def __init__(self, path, header=None):
        self.data = path
        self.header= header
        
    def read(self):
        with open(self.data, 'r') as f:
            data = [x.split(',') for x in f.readlines()]
            return data
    def printer(self):
        if self.header:
            a,b,c,d,e = self.header
            yield(f'{a:^10} {b:^15} {c:^25}{d:10}{e:^10}')
        for i in self.read():
#              print(i)
             yield f'{i[0]:^10}| {i[1]:^10} | {i[2]:^10} | {i[3]:^10} | {i[4]:^10}'

headers= ['id', 'date', 'status', 'number', 'email']
data_frame = complete_list('yes.txt',header = headers).printer()
```

output

```
    id          date                status          number      email   
   1434   | "2021-08-13 06:31:59" |   unread   | 082196788998 | kuse.hamdy@gmail.com

   1433   | "2021-08-13 06:09:41" |   unread   | 081554220007 | ritaambarwati1@umsida.ac

   1432   | "2021-08-13 05:35:07" |   unread   | 081911075017 | rifqinaufalfayyadh@gmail.com
```

Comment: remove the pointless `f.readlines()]` you can iterate directly over a file object

Answer (score 0):

The `pandas` library is the perfect tool for that

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=",", names=['id', 'date', 'status', 'number', 'email'])
print(df)


     id                 date  status       number                         email
0  1434  2021-08-13 06:31:59  unread  82196788998          kuse.hamdy@gmail.com
1  1433  2021-08-13 06:09:41  unread  81554220007   ritaambarwati1@umsida.ac.id
2  1432  2021-08-13 05:35:07  unread  81911075017  rifqinaufalfayyadh@gmail.com
```

Comment: is there any specific reason why I should've done this instead of using OOP? I want to use OOP and to automatize things because later on, I will use many other CSV files and not duplicate the data

Comment: i tried this code and all the data comes into index, and the rest of the column is just NaN values

Comment: @JackZakiZakiulFahmiJailani What do you mean by OOP *specifically*? You seem to mean "writing a class definition".